# Is there a more concise method to get the user.email?

Tags: python

From the a group I can get its users, and use for-loop I can get the user.emal:

```
group = Group.objects.get(name=to_group_name)

    users_qs = group.user_set.all()

    to_emal_list = []
    for user in users_qs:
        to_emal_list.append(user.email)
```

But, is there a more concise method in python to get the emails? I mean if I can use one line code to do with that. something like `lambda` map method for list.

I tried use :

```
user_list = list(users_qs)
to_email_list = map(lambda user: user["email"], user_list)
```

But you know this will fail, the user in user_list is a object.

Comment: List comprehensions are your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, depending on the object type, `user["email"]` is not the same as `user.email`. The map would probably work fine if you accessed the object correctly

However, you're missing list comprehensions

```
emails = [user.email for user in group.user_set.all()]
```